# Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths error with netzke

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs4, netzke

I have rails 3.1.0 & ruby 1.9.2 playing around with netzke & extjs4. I couldn't get extjs integrated with rails. please help.

I am following [this](http://writelesscode.com/blog/2010/06/14/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/) tutorial

I have defined the symbolic path for the extjs & icon library & ran the server.

Error is being raised at `<%= netzke_init %>` in the application layout. I am having the following error:

> Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths in Welcome#index/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css isn't in paths: /home/dreamachine/mywork/netzke_task_manager/app/assets/images, /home/dreamachine/mywork/netzke_task_manager/app/assets/javascripts, /home/dreamachine/mywork/netzke_task_manager/app/assets/stylesheets, /home/dreamachine/mywork/netzke_task_manager/vendor/assets/stylesheets, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switched from extjs 4.1.x to 4.0.7. Basically I have switched the VM,  now have Rails 3.2.5 ruby 1.9.3 & extjs 4.0.7, everything is working fine now.